# Maven online training

Tags: maven

I'm some kind of 'Maven expert' in my company, the problem being that I have a good basic knowledge of Maven, but I'm absolutely not an expert when it comes to release, etc...

I'm desperately searching for some kind of good online training for Maven that is not for beginners and that will speak about release and other advanced stuff.
I have no problem to have a course that starts at the very beginning of Maven, but I want to go further than basic dependency management, basic lifecycle and simple project build, my real goal being to be comfortable with full Maven release.

Has anyone a good website, or something for me ?

Thank you,

Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that's broader than just Maven. Because what you do with Maven is determined by the dev process.

If you're interested in general in dev/release process, you could research Continuous Deliver topic as well as Continuous Integration. You could start with [Continuous Delivery book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912) which gives a good perspective on both CI & CD (it's pretty boring though).

As for the videos, you could just search in the internet for Continuous Delivery. I like in particular videos from [Sam Newman](https://samnewman.io/).

As for the Maven itself, there are books like [Maven Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/pdf/mvnref-pdf.pdf) or [Apache Maven 2 Effective Implementation](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/apache-maven-2-effective-implementation) (which is a bit old, but Maven was pretty stable from the end user perspective, so not much changed).